# Creating new txt file from Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, text, save

I need to create text file from the MS Excel and I would like to do it in automatic way. For the input I have already created several Excel sheets and now I manually have to copy paste from Excel to Notepad (ordinary text editor).

So the task would be in 3 steps:

1. create some button or something that will trigger Excel to copy all from 2 Excel sheets to one txt file
2. If possible before copy, extract the values (not formulas) and perform remove duplicates (to remove duplicated lines)
3. if one cell in excel is yes, copy that line to Excel (in contrary ignore).

But I do not know from where to start. I know how to program in Java, but I do not know from where to start here in Excel. Can you instruct me what should I read to understand what I have to do and is there some code examples how of some similar code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can start from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd439413(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+write+text+file